# How to specify a Windows USB com port instead of Linux dev/port in Python

Tags: python, windows, serial-port, pyserial

I am trying to run the python **ramses rf-master** script on a windows 10 PC.The documentation says that the script called client.py is invoked by entering

**python client.py monitor /dev/ttyUSB0 -o packet.log**

The problem I have is that the serial com port 'dev/ttyUSB0' does not relate to any of the USB com ports on a windows PC. I know that I need to change the **/dev/ttyUSB0** part, to somehow specify that my COM7 USB serial port is to be used.

I have tried, COM7 , (COM7) and similar values and get differing error results all relating to the script not finding the serial port.

I have run the command **python -m serial.tools.list_ports -v** and the results show

**COM1
desc: Communications Port (COM1)
hwid: ACPI\PNP0501\1**

**COM7
desc: USB Serial Device (COM7)
hwid: USB VID:PID=1B4F:9206 SER=5&DC4A972&0&1 LOCATION=1-1:x.0**

**2 ports found**

What is the correct way to specify the COM7 port in the command when invoking the script.

This is my first attempt at using Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way on a Windows PC to specify a Com port in this command should be

**python client.py monitor COM7 -o packet.log**

But there is a problem with the **Ramses rf-master** script in that it errors on this command if there are options included after the com port. This has now been reported to its author.

The script will run sucessfully without the options if you enter just

**python client.py monitor COM7**

Answer (score 0):

To specify a Windows USB COM port instead of a Linux dev port in Python, you can use the `serial.Serial()` function. The syntax is:

```
import serial

# Open the serial port
ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)

# Read data from the serial port
data = ser.readline()

# Close the serial port
ser.close()
```

The COM1 in the above code is the Windows USB COM port. You can find the correct COM port number by opening Device Manager on Windows.

Here is an example of a complete Python script that reads data from a Windows USB COM port:

```
import serial

# Open the serial port
ser = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)

# Read data from the serial port
data = ser.readline()

# Close the serial port
ser.close()

# Print the data
print(data)
```